# Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException : The given data was invalid. Called when trying to get the json from a response while testing

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-testing

I have the following test:

```
public function testStoreMemberValidation()
{
    $response = $this->withExceptionHandling()->post('/api/members', [
        "name" => "Eve",
        "age" => "invalid"
    ], ['X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest']);

    dd($response->json());
};
```

I am trying to assert that the response is of the form of a validation error. The controller method is as follows:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'age' => 'required|integer',
    ]);

    Member::create($data);
}
```

However, whenever I call any assertion which calls `$response->json()` (which is most of them) I get an exception:

> Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException : The given data was invalid.

**How can I perform assertions on this response without throwing this error?**

Note, I am using Laravel 5.7.

Comment: Laravel does that by default, so it seems somewhere down the line (i.e. in a base test case class or something) you’ve added `$this->withoutExceptionHandling`.

Comment: Also, you can use `$this->postJson()` to avoid adding the `X-Requested-With` header manually, and you can test for validation errors using `$response->assertJsonValidationErrors('field_name')`.

Comment: Thanks @MartinBean, changing it to `$this->postJson()` seems to have fixed it. I'm fairly sure I haven't called `$this->withoutExceptionHandling()` anywhere though.

Answer (score 12):

you have the `withExceptionHandling()` in your test, remove it and it should work.

```
$response = $this->withExceptionHandling()->post('/api/members', [
        "name" => "Eve",
        "age" => "invalid"
    ], ['X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest']);
```

should be

```
$response = $this->post('/api/members', [
            "name" => "Eve",
            "age" => "invalid"
        ], ['X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest']);
```

Comment: Also ran into the same issue. Removing `withExceptionHandling` does clear the error. Is there a risk with that? I feel like the test should pass either way.